# Glyphs disappearing from PDF run running PDF/X-1a preflight

Tags: pdf

My printer needs PDF/X-1a. I have a document created in indesign that has a lot of illustrations in PDF created by other applications. The original PDF of the entire document looks fine.

When I run the PDF/X-1a preflight in Acrobat I get errors that glyphs are missing in the embedded subset and special characters in the illustration PDFs get replace by boxes.

"Glyphs missing in embedded font"

The special characters are correct in the file before running the preflight.

How might I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern is printing the document, [print it as an image](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/quick-fix-print-pdf-image.html), rather than as mixed text and image.

You can also export the document by ["printing" the PDF **to** PDF](https://www.lifewire.com/print-to-pdf-4147601), again, as an image, effectively transforming the glyphs in a font to an image.

Comment: I have to send the PDF to a printer for distribution.

Comment: Yes, and if you print the PDF *as* a PDF, with **images** replacing the glyph characters, that should serve your needs. The resulting PDF will be larger, but have no need for any font, embedded, installed or otherwise.

Comment: But the printer will not accept an image PDF.